# Linkage between files - how exactly does it work?

Tags: c++

So I've been reading about this but couldn't find anything that'd explain the behavior of this code below to me:
header.hpp:

```
class TESTING{
private:
    int num;

public:
    TESTING(int);
};

void testing(int, int);
```

def.cpp:

```
#include "header.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

TESTING::TESTING(int num = 100){
    this->num = num;
    cout << "init with: " << this->num << endl;
}

void testing(int a = 500, int b = 200){
    cout << "a: " << a << ", b: " << b << endl;
}

int main(){
    TESTING test1;
    TESTING test2(5);
    testing();
    testing(1);
    testing(1, 2);
}
```

So far so good and working as intended, the output then is:

*init with: 100

init with: 5

a: 500, b: 200

a: 1, b: 200

a: 1, b: 2*

But then when I cut the "int main" function and paste it into the following Main.cpp below

Main.cpp:

```
#include "header.hpp"

int main(){
    //TESTING test1;//error: assumed to be default constructor
    TESTING test2(5);
    //testing();//error: too few arguments
    //testing(1);//error: too few arguments
    testing(1, 2);
}
```

I'd get the errors mentioned in the comments above but still the output:

*init with: 5

a: 1, b: 2*

Which then means that it does link itself to def.cpp but with some sort of minimum visibility(?).

Why's this happening? 

The purpose of this Main.cpp file is to have the main function that'll run all the other c++ files in that project, is there a **general** better way to achieve that than the way I tried? If so, does that way apply to the code mentioned here? Or is my code just written badly?

P.S: I'm new to c++, please be gentle :d

Comment: u r talking about default arguments. Default arguments must be visible in place where u r using it. Thats why everyone write it in headers usually

Comment: You can't have compilation errors _and_ runtime output...

Comment: Perhaps I should've made it more clear. This code would crash with errors in those lines where I later on added '//' for the rest of it to work.

Comment: The errors you get are nothing to do with linkage, you're getting errors during compilation, which happens before linking. The problem is simply visibility, because you're trying to use things in main.cpp that haven't been declared in that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default arguments don't magically transfer across source files. Think about it - how is the compiler processing main.cpp supposed to know that, in a different source file, you gave default arguments to some parameters?

Formally, default arguments are specific to any given scope:

> **8.3.6/4** For non-template functions, default arguments can be added in later declarations of a function in the same scope. Declarations in
>   different scopes have completely distinct sets of default arguments...

Even in the same source file, you can declare the same function to have different default arguments in different scopes. The compiler would happily substitute whatever default arguments, if any, are specified by the declaration visible in the current scope.

---

On an unrelated note, the word "linkage" is a term of art - it has a very specific meaning in C++. This notion of linkage is largely irrelevant to your question, at least insofar as it relates to default arguments (I just point it out for the benefit of readers who might be confused by the question's title). The set of default arguments is not part of the function name or signature, and doesn't affect its linkage, its ability to be used across scopes and translation units.

Comment: Alright, so using the default arguments in different places (such as header.hpp in this example) fixes it for this code, what about the rest of the content in those functions though? How does it know it should reach def.cpp when nothing implies it even exists?

Comment: In response to that unrelated note: I thought it was weird I couldn't find a question like this elsewhere with this keyword :P What term would you use here?

Comment: @MrGuy: The declaration in header.cpp (`void testing(int, int);`) tells it that the function exists. That's the very _purpose_ of the declaration! The linker then automatically locates that function for you and finds it in def.cpp; it can do so because functions have names and such.

Comment: Ah, *that* is where the notion of "linkage" comes in: "A name is said to have linkage when it might denote the same object, reference, function, type, template, namespace or value as a name introduced by a declaration in another scope" (this includes "in another source file"). It is, of course, the job of a linker, not a compiler, to resolve references to the same function, say, to the actual implementation of said function when it assembles the final program out of individually compiled translation units. Note that the set of default arguments is not part of a name, or function signature.